# Set Core Data to lazy load to-one relationship

Tags: core-data, afnetworking, afincrementalstore

I'm using [AFIncrementalStore](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore) to connect my iOS application to my REST API. When I load my initial view controller, I create an NSFetchRequest that loads the latest 100 `Events` (NSManagedObjects) into view. The problem is that each `Event` has a 1:1 relationship with a `Group` object, and as soon as the `Event` is loaded, the incremental store is asked to fill that `Group` object, which in my case triggers an individual request to the server for each of the 100 `Events`.

I can see a couple ways to solve this problem, such as not requesting `Groups` from the server if they are already saved locally, caching the network request, or not storing the relationship in the NSManagedObject. But ideally, the `Group` object could start out as a Fault and only request to be filled once one of its field is accessed, similar to what happens with one-to-many relationships. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation that says how to force a one-to-one relationship in core data to be lazy-loaded. Is it possible?

Comment: I've run into this problem also.   I solved it for now by doing a one-to-many, knowing that there is only ever going to be one object there.  That feels hackish though.   I thought MAYBE 'fetched properties' would be the answer cause they are basically properties which cause a fetch, which seem to make sense in this case.  However, I couldn't figure out how to access the predicate information in my requestForFetchRequest:withContext.  Not only that, but seems like fetched properties are Arrays ANYWAY (one-to-many?).   Guess I am a CoreData newb.  I tweeted @mattt this link though...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

From AFIncrementalStore.h:

```
/**
Returns whether the client should fetch remote relationship values for a
particular managed object. This method is consulted when a managed object
faults on a particular relationship, and will call
`-requestWithMethod:pathForRelationship:forObjectWithID:withContext:` if `YES`.
@param relationship The relationship of the specifified managed object
@param objectID The object ID for the specified managed object.
@param context The managed object context for the managed object.
@return `YES` if an HTTP request should be made, otherwise `NO.  */

- (BOOL)shouldFetchRemoteValuesForRelationship:(NSRelationshipDescription*)
        relationship forObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
        inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

If so, you could set this with

```
- (BOOL)shouldFetchRemoteValuesForRelationship:(NSRelationshipDescription *)relationship forObjectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    return NO;
}
```

in your `AFRESTClient <AFIncrementalStoreHTTPClient>` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling this as well.  Looks like one-to-one relations will always be eager loaded.  One way around this could be to declare it as a one-to-many relation so that it automatically does a lazy load instead.  Then in your model class, you can have a method that returns the first one in the set.